# Regex with Transcript data (Theathre)

Tags: python, regex

```
**Jacke:** Some text... is here?
**Hipster:** Some text... is here?
**Hipster** (ruft): Some text... is here?
**Aluhut** (brüllt hysterisch): Some text... is here?
```

I tried with regex to get only the text, not the first words... so only this

```
Some text... is here?
Some text... is here?
Some text... is here?
Some text... is here?
```

is that possible? this is my regex until now..

```
([*]{2}[a-zA-Zäüö:]+[*]{2}[:]*.)([^\n]*)
```

UPDATE:
Is there a way to filter out something like this

```
*test* Hello it's me
(test) Hello it's me
(*test*) Hello it's me *test*
*(test)* Hello it's me **test**
```

Result for all of this is:

```
Hello it's me
Hello it's me
Hello it's me
Hello it's me
``
```

Comment: Maybe all you need is `line.replace("**", "").split(': ', maxsplit=1)[-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could optionally match the trailing part between parenthesis, and omit the first capture group to match the whole first part.

Capture the part that follows in a capture group.

```
[*]{2}[a-zA-Zäüö:]+[*]{2}:*(?:\s*\([^()]*\):)?\s+(\S.*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `[*]{2}[a-zA-Zäüö:]+` Match `**` and 1+ occurrences of any char listed in the character class
- `[*]{2}:*` Match `**` and optional `:`
- `(?:\s*\([^()]*\):)?` Optionally match whitespace chars followed by a part in parenthesis and `:`
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\S.*)` Capture group 1, match a non whitespace char and the rest of the line

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EXPcV9/1)

Example code using re.findall which gives the value of the capture group:

```
import re
 
regex = r"[*]{2}[a-zA-Zäüö:]+[*]{2}:*(?:\s*\([^()]*\):)?\s+(\S.*)"
 
s = ("**Jacke:** Some text... is here?\n"
    "**Hipster:** Some text... is here?\n"
    "**Hipster** (ruft): Some text... is here?\n"
    "**Aluhut** (brüllt hysterisch): Some text... is here?")
 
print(re.findall(regex, s))
```

Output

```
[
'Some text... is here?',
'Some text... is here?',
'Some text... is here?',
'Some text... is here?'
]
```

Comment: that works very well, thanks. I edited the question because now I also got another problem here... Which seems to me a bit more difficult to handle

Comment: @CoderGer What is the other problem that occurred?

Comment: @CoderGer That seems like a different question. What are the rules for the added strings? There are `*` and `()` in the strings, what is the rule to match `Hello it's me` and not `example:`? Is there always a `-` in the string? There can be many ways to capture that text, like for example `^[()*].*?[()*:]\s+(\w.*?)\s*(?:\*.*\*)?$` https://regex101.com/r/CUTubE/1

Comment: I updated the question again , there was some missundestanding right there

Comment: @CoderGer Then you would have to match all possible variations at the start of the string that should not be captured. And for the last 2 strings, also match to exclude the possible endings with the `**` like `^(?:\*\(.*?\)\*|\(\*.*?\*\)|\*\*.*?\*\*|\*[^*]*\*|\([^()]*\)):*(?:\s*\([^()]*\):)?\s+(\S.*?)(?:\*.+\*)?$` https://regex101.com/r/Vo9HBc/1